# Managing simultaneous requests in azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-load-balancer

I am trying to build an Azure Durable function to orchestrate the execution sequences between multiple azure functions. Sometimes few of those functions are required to be executed parallel, sometimes in sequence. Its all based on some JSON configuration files.

But I am expecting my durable function being called by more than 1000 consumers and this every minute there is a probability of 1000 hits to the durable functions end point. Since internally durable function uses queues and tables, individual calls from durable functions will be organized, but what are the solutions available in azure to manage the situation of large number of hits in this durable function's API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through this [load balancing solution documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview#decision-tree-for-load-balancing-in-azure) in Azure to decide on best load balancing solution to use in your case.

Given if it is a HTTP based application and based on the service provided, you can take a look at

- [Azure FrontDoor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview): It is a modern cloud CDN solution which provides fast, reliable, and secure access between your users and your applications’ static and dynamic web content across the globe. You can [enable caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-caching?pivots=front-door-standard-premium) on the frontdoor to reduce the calls made to your backend. You can also secure your application with [WAF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/afds-overview).
- [Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview): It is a regional load balancer for a web application, where you can take advantage of [features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/features) like WAF, auto-scaling, URL based routing etc.

Based on your requirements you can use both application gateway and front door together, more information can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#when-should-we-deploy-an-application-gateway-behind-front-door-).